# Proving finite second moment given $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nE(|X|1_{n<|x|\le n+1}) <\infty$

Tags: probability, expectation

I am given that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nE(|X|1_{n<|X|\le n+1})<\infty$ and I am trying to prove or disprove that $E(|X|^2)<\infty$. I have been attempting to replicate a tail probability argument similar to what one does to find that $E(X)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nP(X=n)$ to prove this, but I have not been getting very far. Can anyone provide a nudge in the right direction? Side note: This is not the exact problem I was given, just a twist on it that I am exploring in order to solve the real problem.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean, but I would prefer a nudge or a starting point over the answer I guess.

Comment: Last time I answered one of your questions (...which is, in fact, pretty close to this one) you didn't give any feedback; nor did you care to accept or upvote the answer. And it seems that, so far, you haven't accepted/upvoted any answer at all - that's why I was asking.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware that was a thing. On one of my first posts either I submitted or I read someone not to provide feedback once the question had been answered(I suppose for efficiency's sake) so I always just stop talking once my question has been answered. I can upvote though in the future.

Comment: It's nice to let the person, who answered your question, know that you appreciated the answer... by upvoting and/or accepting the answer [the preferred way] and/or writing some thanks [which is discouraged by some users, as you mentioned in your comment].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. Show that $\mathbb{E}(1_{n<|X| \leq n+1} |X|^2) \leq (n+1) \mathbb{E}(1_{n< |X| \leq n+1} |X|) \leq 2n \mathbb{E}(1_{n< |X| \leq n+1} |X|)$.
2. Conclude from
   $$\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}(1_{n< |X| \leq n+1} |X|^2)$$
   and step 1 that
   $$\mathbb{E}(X^2) \leq 2\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} n \mathbb{E}(1_{n<|X| \leq n+1} |X|)<\infty.$$